# Locating changepoints in multiple regression model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have some experimental data with a response variable (y) and multiple explanatory variables (x1 to x4). Zero values in the explanatory variable fields are the experimental controls.

```
    x1      x2    x3     x4     y
0.082494269 1   16.43   328   -0.325
0.195673137 5   27.07   318   -0.3625
0.219937331 7   45.44   360   -0.525
0.059035684 4   32.68   203   -0.4125
0.381432485 8   71.38   167   -0.475
0.040377394 3   16.43   135   -0.425
0.055993298 1   21.88   154   -0.3875
0           0   0        0    -0.325
0.112635472 5   33.63   328   -0.3625
0.217039159 7   45.83   200   -0.475
0.035330022 2   17.78   117   -0.48
0.234216386 6   51.79   119   -0.45
0.085048722 6   39.71   98    -0.445
0.064759017 1   27.46   133   -0.3625
0.123863896 7   36.61   82    -0.4625
0.18932145  6   44.21   74    -0.425
0.409036425 8   62.38   154   -0.525
0           0   0       0     -0.275
0.493185115 8   120.3   103   -0.5625
0.132214199 5   26.61   222   -0.425
0           0   0       0     -0.3375
```

My regression models are usually bivariate (y~x1) but all the x values here could be used as predictors. What I'm trying to do is find (if there is one) the point at which the y value changes significantly using whichever combination of x values is required to elicit a change.

I'm using R and have briefly looked at the 'chngpt' package but it's a little beyond me at the moment. Has anyone had any experience using this package and is this appropriate for my purpose? Could anyone demonstrate how to do what I'm trying to do with the data provided?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a statistics question, not a programming question. It would be more on-topic on stats.stackexhcange.com. Neither site is a code writing service, and requests to "demonstrate how to do what I'm trying to do with the data provided" will probably elicit negative responses. If you just want someone to recommend a method, write code for you and explain it, I would suggest finding a consultant or a private tutor.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comments.